# Flutter switch between local data and remote data

Tags: flutter

In a Flutter app the user must be able to see the retrieved data from an API also when there is no network, e.g. in a house basement. I'm able to retrieve the data from the Api and to store it in a local sqflite db. I'm also able to check whether there is network or not. But how do I implement the flow in order to show local data or remote data? Is it possible to do it in the same screen or do I need two screens? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
Thank you for all the answers, but I don't check where to fill in the getData() method now. I post what I've done so far:

```
class WorkAtPop extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WorkAtPop createState() => _WorkAtPop();
}

class _WorkAtPop extends State<WorkAtPop> {
  final String title = 'Work@Pop';
  final bgcolor = HexToColor('#ffffff');
  final list = List();
  final isLoading = false;

  List<DropdownChoices> workatpopdropdownchoices = <DropdownChoices>[
DropdownChoices(title: 'Refresh', action: 'refresh', route: '/workatpop'),
  ];

  bool _isVpnEnabled = false;
  bool _isLoading = true;

  void checkVpn() async {
    var isEnabled = await ApiService().isVpnEnabled();
    setState(() => _isVpnEnabled = isEnabled);
    setState(() => _isLoading = false);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkVpn();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
  appBar: BaseAppBar(title: title, appBar: AppBar(), dropdownChoices: workatpopdropdownchoices),
  backgroundColor: bgcolor,
  body: new Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
    color: bgcolor,
    child: (_isLoading)
            ? new Center(
                child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : new Container(
      child: new Text('here my data displayed as list, vpn=$_isVpnEnabled'),
    )
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Now if VPN is enabled I retrieve the data from the api else from the local db. The API is storing the data into the db each time it is called.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're handling everything, it will be easy for you to do so. It's possible only in a single screen.

```
List<PodoClass> data;

if(internet()) {
data = fecthDataFromNetwork(); // load fron internet
} else {
data = loadLocalData(); // load from database
}

processData(data); // process your data
```

I hope you got some idea.

Answer (score 1):

If internet is available get data from server and store it in localdb, and if internet is not available get already stored data from localdb.

```
List<PodoClass> data;

void feachdata() async{

if(isInternet()) {
data = await DataFromNetwork(); // load from internet
storetolocaldb(data); // store to local for later use
} else {
data = getLocalData(); // load from database
}
displaydata(data); // process your data

}
```

hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

you can store retrieved data from an API to a local db and can fetch it on both cases offline/online.. Also you can update the db if any new data available in the api

```
void getData() {
getStoredDataFromDb().then((data){
   if(data !=null){
     populateUI();
     checkForAnyUpdate();
   }
   else {
     if(hasInternetconnection)
       getDatafromApi();
     }
     else{
       loadMockOrOldData();}
 };
 getDatafromApi().then((response){
    insertDataIntoTheDatabase(response);
 };
}
```